# Protractor phantomsJS hangs on Selenium standalone server started at http://

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I'm trying to make protractor work with Chrome for development and PhantomJS for the server. The problem is that when I try to run protractor with PhantomJS it hangs at:

> Selenium standalone server started at http://...

Nothing happens after that. I've tried a lot of different configurations, searched for open bugs or patches, but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone have a clue?

My configuration:

```
capabilities:
{
    'browserName': 'phantomjs',     
    'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true',  '--web-security=false', '--debug=true'],
    'phantomjs.binary.path': './node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your phantomJS config.

Ex : for Windows : you should add phantomjs.exe dir to the PATH, and be sur (for WS) to delete 'phantomjs.binary.path' :

```
   capabilities:
   {
       'browserName': 'phantomjs',     
   }
```

then:

```
protractor test/protractor-conf.js
```

For more details, you can refer to this link :

http://attester.ariatemplates.com/usage/phantom.html